# Highlight current Menu Item is not working, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Highlight current Menu Item is not working, why?
I think I'm doing everything ok, but it's not working.

Can you give me a little help?

**Html:**

```
<section id="menu-container">
    <div id="bar"><img src="border.png" /></div>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html1">Home2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html2">Home3</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html3">Home4</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html4">Home5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){

    var url = window.location.href; 

    $("#menu ul  li a").each(function() {

        if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.active{
    background-color:#0C3;
}
```

Comment: In what way doesn't this work? Are you getting errors? Could the problem be related to something else? Your code works for me in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gF6js/8/). Try alerting or logging the `url` vs `this.href` and see how they compare. `console.log(url+' == '+this.href);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).attr("href")` to get the `href` value from your links, since you are already using JQuery.

Combine that with andrew's suggestion to get the end of the current url and you now have better values to test in your `if` statement.

```
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.href.split('/'); 
    url = url[url.length-1];

    $("#menu a").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this); // to minimize DOM traversal
        if (url === $this.attr("href")) {
            $this.closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

An even better option would be to use advanced JQuery selectors:

```
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.href.split('/'); 
    url = url[url.length-1];

    $("#menu a[href='" + url + "'").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: What is the problem and why does your code solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.location.href // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120946/highlight-current-menu-item-is-not-working-why
```

try:

```
 var url = window.location.href.split('/');
 url = url[url.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href;
$('#menu a').each(function(k,s) {
    if(this == url){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3usdk/3/) for the solution. The second link in the fiddle should be the active link.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working. I think that i will think about other solution because with this method looks impossible!

Comment: I believe the update to my post should work. Sorry it's been so long I had to go away from my computer for a while. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3usdk/3/) for the solution.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to get this working? If not I'm willing to try and help a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately still can´t put this working, I'm looking for other solutions!